# CSS Background-size one parameter

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a better grasp on HTML/CSS and very often I see things like 
`background-size: 100px`

what does it mean when there is only one parameter given for something that requires a length and width? Does it default to only defining the length and scaling the width according to the image? Or does it default to the width?

Comment: One-value syntax: the value defines the width of the image, the height is implicitly set to 'auto' [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only one size is defined it's handled as width and the height automatically set to `auto`.

From [the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Syntax):

```
/* Keywords syntax */
background-size: cover
background-size: contain

/* One-value syntax: the value defines the width of the image, the height is implicitly set to 'auto' */
background-size: 50%
background-size: 3em
background-size: 12px
background-size: auto

/* Two-value syntax: the first value defines the width of the image, the second its height */
background-size: 50% auto
background-size: 3em 25%
background-size: auto 6px
background-size: auto auto

/* Values for the multiple backgrounds, defined by background-image, may be listed separated by commas */
background-size: auto, auto     /* Do not confuse this with background-size: auto auto */
background-size: 50%, 25%, 25%
background-size: 6px, auto, contain

background-size: inherit
```

Comment: so say i have background-size: 50% and that targets the width, what does auto target? Does it leave the height as what the original image's height is? or does it scale it down by 50% as well

Comment: It holds the aspect ratio of the background image. Note that `background-size: 50%;` doesn't resize the background image by 50%, but instead sets it to 50% of the width of the container. The height is then calculated as needed to hold the aspect ratio.

Comment: so an image that's 100x100 would not be resized to 50x50 with the background-size property right? it would crop it to 50x50?

Comment: The percentage isn't of the image size but the container's size. If your container is 200px x 200px and you set `background-size: 50%`, the background image will be resized (not cropped) to 100 x auto (auto holding the aspect ratio), regardless of what the original image dimensions were.

Comment: alright - thank you very much for clarifying! I appreciate all the help